# Setting up CodeBlocks with Ming

Tags: code-blocks

I had CodeBlocks 10 and used to get the same error while compiling a C program, then I uninstalled it and installed CodeBlocks 13.12 which comes with Ming, but I still get the same error messages when I compile C program.  Plz tell what to do so that I can successfully compile C programs.
[image]

[image]

Comment: here's my one if it helps http://i.imgur.com/Pjw4SQ1.png  perhaps you should try to install them separately rather than just expecting it to work from some bundled setup.  And try to work it from the command line. And check that those files really exist in that path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two likely scenarios for this issue:

1. Your download/MinGW installation is corrupt and you need to reinstall.
2. You have a second MinGW installation on your system.

Since you just upgraded, each is a distinct possibility. I would carefully uninstall all Codeblocks/MinGW installations, then re-download and reinstall.

On a side note, I have personally found the best option is to pick the [codeblocks-13.12-setup.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/) for Windows (without MinGW), then separately install the latest version of [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/). I personally prefer TDM64 since you can build both 32-bit (with the proper compiler and linker flag) and 64-bit apps with it, but TDM32 works fine.

---

*Note that you can get the latest version of CodeBlocks from the [CodeBlocks download page](https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/).*

---

FYI, a separate TDM-GCC install will let you pick your own folder which might help with any potential conflicts. If you do install TDM-GCC separately, you don't have to install it in `C:\MinGW`. Just remember to pick an install folder without spaces, though.

[image: MingGW TDM-GCC64 Compiler Settings]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have 2 folders in my C drive, "MinGW" and "MingGW32-xy" , I guess the second one got installed with Python(x,y), can you suggest what to do now, I need to Python.

Comment: i get same errors even after manually deleting "MinGW" and setting "MinGW32-xy" as compiler in codeblocks.

Comment: Hmm. The errors you're getting seem to imply MinGW can't find all its bits and pieces. I don't use Python(x,y but it may be possible the package(s) using that version of MinGW do not implement all the tools. I would suggest you *completely* uninstall Code::Blocks (deleting residual directories, etc.), installing the *non-bundled* version I linked to, then install TDM-GCC OR use the official web installer from mingw.org. I would then make sure there was only one entry for any MinGW compiler in my User PATH and system Path variable and that pointed to the TDM-GCC OR MinGW.org install of MinGW.

Comment: C:\Programs\TDM-GCC-64\bin; is what I have in my system Path.

Comment: Regarding python xy, I would carefully copy & remove any "MinGW32-xy" PATH/Path entries if they exist, then add them back only if something breaks.

Comment: Thanks friend, the key point you mentioned that there should not be multiple MinGW resolved my problem, I uninstalled CodeBlocks and Python, deleted both MinGW folders and Fortran folder, then I installed Python, it installs MinGW, then installed earlier version of CodeBlocks which comes without MinGW, now Python worked and C program in CodeBlocks compiled, then I added Fortran compiler folder in C drive and used Notepad++ to write Fortran program which compiled from command prompt in Fortran folder, so everything working separately and problem solved! Thank you for guiding :)

Comment: Awesome. I'm happy everythying worked out. Happy coding! =)